# Android GCM server disable auto notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I use `GCM` for notification

If application closed , `GCM` send auto notification to mobile

I want this notification disabled and only use `onReceive` class

If application closed , receive 2 notification and duplicated !

1- From server

2- From `onReceive`

Please help for solve this problem

Comment: What !?! Send me your question in Persian and I will translate it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use  [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). You should have a preference that contains the value if the user should be alerted or not. Set the preference value to false/true. In youir  [`GCMIntentService`](https://github.com/googlearchive/solutions-mobile-shopping-assistant-backend-java/blob/master/MobileAssistant-Tutorial/MobileAssistant/src/com/google/samplesolutions/mobileassistant/GCMIntentService.java) in the  [`onMessage`](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/#response) method, check the value of the preference if its false, just do nothing.

Have a look at this, it shows  [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)